# How to deploy a development store view into live site?

Tags: magento-1.7, store-view

We have created an extra development store view in our existing live Magento website. Now we're happy with the changes, what is the best way to make this development store view primary for the site?
Important is that order numbers must remain the same after changing. So we can't just set the new store view as the new default one.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Forgive me, but how does default store view effect order numbers?

Comment: @Shredder per storeview you have a different order increment ID. Both start at 0 but one is prefixed with "1" and the second with "2".

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the best way is to put live site in maintenance mode, apply the changes you made to the dev site to like site, then take live site out of maintenance mode. There are also order number manipulation extensions as well as raw MySql queries, but all of that ugliness can be avoided by doing it the hard way. (maint mode)

I've done a few moves and it's best to inconvenience customers slightly in the moment rather than truly make a blunder of sales.